# Linearization of IFF between a binary and an integer

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I'm trying to find the mathematical linearization of this constraint:

p = 0 if and only if s = 0

Where p is binary and **s is an integer >= 0** (thus it cannot be treated as a binary!!!)

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint:

```
  p = 0 if and only if s = 0
  p binary, s non-negative integer
```

is sometimes written as:

```
 p = 0 <=> s = 0
```

This can be restated as the set of implications:

```
  p = 0 => s = 0
  p = 1 => s >= 1
```

If your solver has support for **indicator constraints** this can be implemented as is. If not, we can write:

```
 p <= s <= U⋅p
 s ∈ {0,1,2,..,U}
 p ∈ {0,1}
```

Here U is an upper bound on s. Note that most likely, you will need to write this as two separate inequalities.

Comment: Thanks Erwin!!! Where would I be without your help!